# Expand base-class with more methods from other bundle (by di-service?)

Tags: symfony

I have a 2 Bundles.

Bundle 1:

```
class EntityOne {

    private $_foo;

    public function setFoo($foo)
    {
        $this->_foo = $foo;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->_foo;
    }
}
```

My Service (service.yml)

```
service:
    MyFooProject\Entity:
        class: MyFooProject\Entity\EntityOne
```

Bundle 2:

```
class EntityTwo extends \MyFooProject\Entity\EntityOne {

    private $_bar;

    public function setBar($bar)
    {
        $this->_bar = $bar;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->_bar;
    }
}
```

My Service (service.yml)

```
service:
    MyBarProject\Entity\EntityTwo
        parent: MyFooProject\Entity\EntityOne
```

Now I want call Method `setBar()` in Bundle 1 but Symfony didn't find Method `setBar()` from Bundle 2

```
function test()
{
    $oEntity = $this->get(MyFooProject\Entity\EntityOne::class);
    $oEntity->setFoo("foo");
    $oEntity->setBar("bar"),
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Hmmm.  The parent stuff in the service container is for injecting values in the constructor.  It is not going to change the actual class.  More importantly, it is very unusual to define entities as services.  Might want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Found a solution by Event-Handling.